# Запрос JSON в Java

Tags: java, json

нужно написать код для тестирования API через JSON.

1) Нужно сделать запрос серверу и включить туда заголовки (headers) и информацию по имени пользователя и пароль.

2) Нужно прочитать ответ с сервера и подтвердить что пользователь залогинился.

3) После этого, нужно отослать на сервер блок информация для обработки и проверить что она обработана.

Я новичок в этом, раньше не сталкивался. Даже не знаю с чего начать. Пытался пользовать библитеки типа Json Simply но ничего не получилось, я не понимаю как это нужно делать. Если кто знает подскажите или помогите с кодом.

Спасибо.

Comment: Все очень просто. Всю информацию обрабатывает сервер а в ответ отправляет или код 200 (ок) или же код ошибки.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Если ответ не полный/не понятый/не тот, что надо - напиши об этом в комментарии*

1) Хорошее видео по JSON - [YouTube ссылка (на русском)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4Almffj2Gms)

2) Пример `POST` и `GET`, которую я взял за основу для "извлечения данных с бирж":

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;

public class HttpURLConnectionExample {

    private final String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        HttpURLConnectionExample http = new HttpURLConnectionExample();

        System.out.println("Testing 1 - Send Http GET request");
        http.sendGet();

        System.out.println("\nTesting 2 - Send Http POST request");
        http.sendPost();

    }

    // HTTP GET request
    private void sendGet() throws Exception {

        String url = "https://api.kraken.com/0/public/Trades?pair=XXBTZEUR&since=0";

        URL obj = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

        // optional default is GET
        con.setRequestMethod("GET");

        //add request header
        con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);

        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
        System.out.println("\nSending 'GET' request to URL : " + url);
        System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();

        //print result
        System.out.println(response.toString());

    }

    // HTTP POST request
    private void sendPost() throws Exception {

        String url = "https://api.kraken.com/0/public/Ticker?pair=XBTCZUSD";
        URL obj = new URL(url);
        HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

        //add request header
        con.setRequestMethod("POST");
        con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
        con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");

        String urlParameters = "{\"pair\":{\"XBTEUR\"}";

        // Send post request
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
        wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
        wr.flush();
        wr.close();

        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
        System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + url);
        System.out.println("Post parameters : " + urlParameters);
        System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();

        //print result
        System.out.println(response.toString());

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

- Учим, что такое HTTP
- Потом учим, что такое JSON
- Потом смотрим как сформировать и выполнить HTTP запрос в Java
- ?????????
- PROFIT!

Учить в сторону [Apache HttpClient](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/index.html), [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson)/[GSON](https://github.com/google/gson)

Простую консольную программу на Java Вы, надеюсь, знаете как написать?