# Как сделать запрос на api сервер через java

Tags: java, json, api

Необходимо получить информацию о курсе валют , на сайте банка есть api в формате json нужно как получить себе в приложение.
http://www.nbrb.by/APIHelp/ExRates - может кто может глянуть и помочь ?

Comment: Я отвечал на подобный вопрос. Рассмотри вот тут ответы - [Запрос JSON в Java](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/826151/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-json-%D0%B2-java/826173#826173)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Прогоните адрес http://www.nbrb.by/API/ExRates/Currencies/{Cur_ID} через Postman или другое (возможно онлайновое) средство для получения JSON ответов на запросы. Полученный результат с помощью http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ преобразуйте в Java-модель.

Для начала не забудьте в app/build.gradle добавить следующие зависимости

```
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
```

Все модели кладёте в папку model.

Создаёте папку network, и туда кладёте сервис и фабрику.

Код фабрики:

```
//Импортируем необходимые классы
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;

//Объявляем фабрику - только статичные поля и методы
public class ApiFactory {

    private static final String ROOT_URL = "http://www.nbrb.by/API/ExRates";

    static Retrofit buildRetrofit() {
        return new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(ROOT_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
    }

    public static ApiService getService() {
        return buildRetrofit().create(ApiService.class);
    }
}
```

Код сервиса:

```
//Импортируйте получившиеся у Вас в JSON-POJO модели
import com.YOUR_BRAND.YOUR_APP_NAME.model.Currency;
import com.YOUR_BRAND.YOUR_APP_NAME.model.Rate;
import com.YOUR_BRAND.YOUR_APP_NAME.model.Dynamics;
//В данном случае они должны быть в папке model вашего проекта

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.GET;
import retrofit2.http.Path;
import retrofit2.http.Query;
import retrofit2.http.Headers;

public interface ApiService {
    @Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
    @GET("/Currencies/{id}") 
    Call<Currency> getCurrency(
        @Path("id") String code)

    @Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
    @GET("/Rates/{id}") 
    Call<Rate> getRate(
        @Path("id") String code,
        @Query("onDate") String onDate,
        @Query("Periodicity") String periodicity,
        @Query("ParamMode") String paramMode)

    @Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
    @GET("/Rates/Dynamics/{id}") 
    Call<Dynamics> getDynamics(
        @Path("id") String code,
        @Query("startDate") String startDate,
        @Query("endDate") String endDate)
}
```

Для отправки запроса и получения результата там где нужно (например в MainActivity) используете следующий код (на примере запроса валюты, два других запроса напишете по аналогии):

```
Call<Currency> call = ApiFactory.getService().getCurrency("1"); //или другой код валюты
call.enqueue(new Callback<Currency>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<Currency> call, Response<Currency> response) {
        if (response.isSuccessful()) {
            //Действия, если запрос прошёл
            //Доступ к ответу на запрос - response.body().getData()
            //он имеет класс Currency

        } else {
            //действия, если запрос не прощёл
            Log.d("myLogs", ErrorUtils.errorMessage(response));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<Currency> call, Throwable t) {}
});
```

В папку network кладёте также классы ApiError и ErrorUtils. Возьмёте их здесь:

[Как отправить POST запрос через Retrofit 2.0?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/885934/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-post-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-retrofit-2-0)

Если будут вопросы, пишите

Comment: Вообщем с получение разобрался и преобразовал в код через онлайн-переводчик этот , немного не понимаю как в самом коде сделать так чтобы отправлялся запрос и получить непосредственно в приложение

Comment: @ВадимОрловский смотрите обновление ответа

Comment: Спасибо огромное , Вы мне очень помогли , мне немного не это нужно было , но благодаря Вам , я нашел все что мне необходимо !